# How to change a desktop background more than once every 10 seconds?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, desktop-customization, regedit

The default windows, background-slideshow's lowest change time is 1 minute. Of course, opening regedit (`WINDOWS + r` and then type `regedit` and `ENTER`) then navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Personalization\Desktop Slideshow` and changing the value of interval will allow you to set the desktop background change speed (in milliseconds).

However, if I set the value below 10,000 (that's 10 seconds in milliseconds) to, for example, 5000 the background still only changes every 10 seconds (even though the value interval key has a value of 5000)

So, my questions are:

1. Why does this happen
2. How do I change this

Comment: Not an answer, but it might make sense to limit this interval to something reasonable since flashing lights/images can trigger seizures in people with photosensitive epilepsy.

Comment: Try using smaller files for the background image, or ones with the exact dimensions of the display. Some time is taken to convert images to the native display resolution, which may slow the rate beyond 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Since you changed the registry, unless there's a process that reads that particular setting regularly (when you change it in the GUI, it's reloaded), you'd need a reboot, or at minimum a logout/login for the value change to be read.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).